# Bokeh and pivot tables

Tags: python, pivot, bokeh

Need some leads. 
I have a spend data with different vendors based on years and their type of industry.

This is close to 65k rows with vendor names repeating and associated spend based on posted years as rows.

I want to use Bokeh to do the following.

1. Have different widgets to select year of spend.
2. Based on my selection sum up spend per vendor / year and project it on Bokeh plot. Potentially, this will show the vendor with maximum impact.

I am not sure if this can be a combined Bokeh function.

Need some high level leads. I have read a lot of posts but I don't seem to find on how I can achieve this.

Comment: Can someone help please? I wish I could include some code.

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing that is hindering you? [Here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html) is a list of bokeh input widgets, you could use the Autocomplete or the Select widget for the year. 2) doesn't seem to pertain bokeh, or are you not sure how to plot what you want to plot? In that case show some example data and an example plot/image of what you want it to look like. What exactly do you mean with "combined Bokeh function"?

Comment: Hello Syntonm, thanks for responding. I have wanted to know if Bokeh can dynamically do pivot tables on a wide range of data and provide me histogram or scatter plot on demand. My data has multiple rows with each row repeating same vendor and different spend

Comment: Bokeh has no inbuilt pivot table as far as I know. Bokeh is mainly concerned with making nice looking output (and a bit of input via widgets), but doesn't really deal with "logic" i.e. if you select this year in this widget update the data in that plot. But because you can dynamically update the data in bokeh plots you can just code that part yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered Bokeh doesn't have any native pivot tables support but you could definitely build a [Bokeh server app](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) where the data shown in the plot(s) is dynamically loaded from the Bokeh server when the user changes selection on the page. This could be realised via a Python callback function executed on the server. On the server side you could use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (possibly in combination with [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)) to perform filtering and data calculation.

Another option would be to use the [Datashader](http://datashader.org/)